# While reading an Excel file in Python, why is the datatype getting changed from number(int) to object?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe Outlet_df derived from an excel file where the column Sellthru Qty only has integer values.

```
outlet_df = pd.read_excel('BW_CPFR_OUTLET_HU10.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')

outlet_df_1 = outlet_df[['Calendar Year/Week','Material','Sellthru Qty']]

outlet_df_1.dtypes
```

Output

```
Calendar Year/Week    float64
Material               object
Sellthru Qty           object
dtype: object
```

The problem is I have to do calculations with the Sellthru Qty. I can't do it if the datatype assigned is not number.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: How is Sellthru Qty formatted in the sheet? Can you show some sample data? You may need an .astype conversion on the column.

Comment: I really don't know how to share the excel data formatting here. All values in the column are numbers. For now, I have found a way around using this code: outlet_df_1 = outlet_df_1.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
But I would like to know how to avoid this issue in the first place. Could you elaborate a bit more about the .astype conversion? Thanks

Comment: Its a type casting function. You could include an image of part of the column and tell us when you right click format cells on a cell in the target column how it is formatted.

Comment: The format is General. Values are all numbers. I don't want to change anything in the Excel file; I want to work on Python only (it's an automation project). The code that I am using works fine. If there is a better way, please let me know.